# Err 22003 - SQL Server IN Error

Tags: sql-server

I have a small query to get data from my table but for some reason don't work sometimes.

[Table TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4bvW.png)

Query #1:

> Error:  22003 - [SQL Server]The conversion of the nvarchar value '5492215893737' overflowed an int column.

```
declare @in_array varchar(128) = '51831,43010'
declare @sql_ varchar (128) = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ARRAYT IN ('+@in_array+')'
select @in_array as 'output'
EXEC (@sql_)
```

Query #2: Works fine

```
declare @in_array varchar(128) = '5492215893737'
declare @sql_ varchar (128) = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ARRAYT IN ('+@in_array+')'
select @in_array as 'output'
EXEC (@sql_)
```

Query #3:

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '5492215893737' overflowed an int column.

```
declare @in_array varchar(128) = '5492215893737, 13737171'
declare @sql_ varchar (128) = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ARRAYT IN ('+@in_array+')'
select @in_array as 'output'
EXEC (@sql_)
```

Query #4:

> Error: [Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'justtest'.
>   42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'thisis'.

```
declare @in_array varchar(128) = 'thisis, justtest'
declare @sql_ varchar (128) = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ARRAYT IN ('+@in_array+')'
select @in_array as 'output'
EXEC (@sql_)
```

I can't change my `@in_array`. I mean that var should be always like 'var1, var2, var3, var4, varN' (`varchar` type)

**#UPDATE:**
With the code provide by Giorgi I get this: second select is not working but why the third is working?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUDJ4.png)

Comment: What is the data type of ARRAYT?

Comment: Hello, is varchar(250)

Answer (score 0):

Those values in an input string should be enclosed in single quotes. Change the variable in the start of the script:

```
set @in_array = '''' + replace(@in_array, ', ', ''',''') + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a string, you need to have enough quotes in your SQL. This should work:

```
declare @in_array varchar(128) = '''5492215893737'', ''13737171'''
declare @sql_ varchar (128) = 'SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ARRAYT IN ('+@in_array+')'
select @in_array as 'output'
EXEC (@sql_)
```